# destructuring with spread operator and typing

Tags: typescript, destructuring, object-destructuring

I have this object:

```
const ABCD = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}
```

I can destructure it, collect the rest of it using the "spread" operator, and type the variables like this:

```
const {a, b, ...restOfIt}: {a: number, b: number} = ABCD;
```

But how do I also type the `restOfIt` on the same line? The following all fail:

```
 const {a, b, ...restOfIt}: {a: number, b: number, ...restOfIt: any} = ABCD;
 const {a, b, ...restOfIt}: {a: number, b: number, restOfIt: any} = ABCD;
```

TypeScript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=73#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggIQMIBEYF4YG8BQMYCGAXDAIwA0eMARiQEyX7AkDMjMAJiQCw4C%20OHLlCRYWAuRqSAdLIBOAU2gB5AGYBJKHwzxkKANz9Bw8NGwSpMWdMUqNWkuJJgArgFtqCuZNoxXHr21MRFRDASEcETNxHxl5JSg1TT5HYj93T28aZwyvOJsEpKgSAjAATyDdUKMIqLELanzbRPsU8xyArN9-TMlmopLyypCDfiA)

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly annotate it? TypeScript should be able to infer the types for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dynamic key definition

```
const {a, b, ...restOfIt}: {a: number, b: number, [key: string]: any} = ABCD;
```

If you know all types in `restOfIt` is `number`, you also can use `number` instead of `any` which is better

```
const {a, b, ...restOfIt}: {a: number, b: number, [key: string]: number} = ABCD;
```

If you already have a type for `restOfIt`, you can use type union

```
type CD = {
  c: number,
  d: number
}
const {a, b, ...restOfIt}: { a: number, b: number} & CD = ABCD;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggIQMIBEYF4YG8BQMYCGAXDAIwA0eMARiQEyX7AkDMjMAJiQCw4C+OHFACeABwCmMVBmxVmMMAFcAttXEAndlwUq16-oNyhIsLAXI0LAOhvrx0APIAzAJJQ+MxKgDcBnEfBobHNLGBsrO0dXdxIRCRAneGQ0TC8UXwF-HGMgswtqa1t7KGc3PhIsQhIlVQ186t0NDwAyKRSknz8Ak2D8woji0pjsKp1azRoG8YsAbQBrcWESaHUASzAAcwBdKb0YD1TkjKA)

Comment: This would break if `a` or `b`  is not `number`

Comment: This works but apparently, in the general case, it can't be made as strict / rigorous as one would want it too. E.g. suppose I had already defined a type `CD` for the `restOfIt`. How would I assert that the `restOfIt` is of type `CD` ?

Comment: @TobiasS. hmm from the question, he defined `a` and `b` as a number type

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I added the part related to `CD` type as you mentioned, we can use type union in that case

Comment: @NickVu quite close now but still, the above code does not really assert the type of `restOfIt` under certain cases. E.g. if I had `type CD = {a: number, c: number,  d: number}`, that would still type check because the entirety of the values is compared against the entirety of the type.

Comment: `that would still type check` you mean it's invalid or valid in the above case? from the inspection of the above code snippet, we can see `restOfIt` has type `{ c: number, d: number }`. Could you add on your expectation in your question, I can try to look into it closely. @MarcusJuniusBrutus

Comment: @NickVu I mean that if you defined `CD` as `type CD = {a: number, c: number,  d: number}` then the code is still found to be VALID, even though `restOfIt` is `{c: number, d: number}` and NOT `{a: number, c: number, d: number}`.

Comment: a union type is to unify `{ a: number, b: number }` and  `{a: number, c: number,  d: number}` to become a new type which is `{ a: number b: number, c: number, d: number }` (merged `a: number` because of duplication). For `...restOfIt`, if you check `restOfIt.a`, it will be invalid because `restOfIt` only contains `c` and `d` @MarcusJuniusBrutus